# How can I exclude a team from a selector?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a Minecraft map and I made a minigame. I have this automatic effect to give infinite regeneration. I want to exclude the people playing the game from regeneration.

The command I had is

```
effect give @a Minecraft:regeneration 10 255 true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it took a long time i finally figured it out.
The exclamation mark (`!`) character is used for not.
So, the command is:

```
effect @a[team=!team1] minecraft:regeneration 10 255 true
```